# Android DialogFramgment loads item from arrayList twice but only on Samsung

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I am cleaning up some code where a DialogFrament i supposed to diaplay items from an ArrayList (ref. "arr" in the code) and then the user can choose severeal items from it and then hit OK. This work fine, no problemo. But, only on Samsung Phones, the DialogFrament lists the item from the ArrayList twice. so, on all the other phone the list displays the values arr[0]->arr[n] but on Samsung(again ONLY on Samsung) the values are arr[0]->arr[n] + arr[0]->arr[n]. Since it's the same code for all android phones but the problem only occurs on Samsung Phones, im out of ideas.

A quick google search pointed me towards a difference in layout rules by Samsung depending on the resolution of their phone but it seeamed unlikely.

**Have any of you heard about this before?**

CODE FOR MY FRAGMENT

```
public ArrayList mSelectedItems;
public int type;
public boolean single = false;

int count;
boolean search;

public int single_item = -1;

public interface CategoriesDialogFragmentListener {
    public void onOkay(ArrayList items, int type);
    public void onCancel();
    public void onSingleOkay(int item, int type);
}

CategoriesDialogFragmentListener mListener;

public void setType(int type_id) {

    /*
    1 = Category
    2 = Genre
    3 = Availability
    */

    type = type_id;
}

public void setSearch(boolean isSearch) {

    search = isSearch;
}
public void setList(ArrayList temp) {

    mSelectedItems = temp;
}

public void isSingle(boolean is_single){
    single = is_single;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try {
        // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        mListener = (CategoriesDialogFragmentListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
    }
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();  // Where we track the selected items
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Set the dialog title
    CharSequence[] arr;
    String title;

    switch(type){
        case 1:
            title = "Välj kategori";
            arr = MainActivity.CATEGORY_STRINGS.toArray(new CharSequence[MainActivity.CATEGORY_STRINGS.size()]);
            single = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            title = "Välj genre";
            arr = MainActivity.GENRE_STRINGS.toArray(new CharSequence[MainActivity.GENRE_STRINGS.size()]);
            single = false;
            break;
        case 3:
            title = "Välj tillgängligheter";
            arr = MainActivity.AVAIL_STRINGS.toArray(new CharSequence[MainActivity.AVAIL_STRINGS.size()]);
            single = false;
            break;
        default:
            title = "ett fel uppstod";
            arr = MainActivity.CATEGORY_STRINGS.toArray(new CharSequence[MainActivity.CATEGORY_STRINGS.size()]);
    }

    if(!single) {
        if(type == 2 && search == false) {
            count = 0;
            builder.setTitle(title).setMultiChoiceItems(arr, null,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                                            boolean isChecked) {

                            //Kod för att starta fragment med valda entiteter
                            /*
                            if(mSelectedItems != null || !mSelectedItems.isEmpty()){
                                for(Object e : mSelectedItems){

                                }
                            }
                            */

                            if (isChecked) {
                                if (count < 5) {
                                    mSelectedItems.add(which);
                                    count++;
                                } else {
                                    new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                            .setTitle(R.string.five)
                                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                    // continue with delete

                                                }
                                            })
                                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                            .show();
                                    ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().setItemChecked(which, false);
                                }

                            } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                                // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                                mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                                count--;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    // Set the action buttons
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
                            // or return them to the component that opened the dialog
                            mListener.onOkay(mSelectedItems, type);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Avbryt", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            CategoriesDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                        }
                    });
        }else{
            builder.setTitle(title).setMultiChoiceItems(arr, null,
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                                            boolean isChecked) {

                            if (isChecked) {

                                mSelectedItems.add(which);

                            } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
                                // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                                mSelectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    // Set the action buttons
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
                            // or return them to the component that opened the dialog
                            mListener.onOkay(mSelectedItems, type);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Avbryt", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            CategoriesDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                        }
                    });
        }
    } else {

        builder.setTitle(title).setSingleChoiceItems(arr, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                single_item = item;
            }
        })
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User clicked OK, so save the mSelectedItems results somewhere
                        // or return them to the component that opened the dialog
                        mListener.onSingleOkay(single_item, type);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Avbryt", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        CategoriesDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
                    }
                });;
    }
    return builder.create();
}
```

}